# how to make a decorator function to be part of class

Tags: python, class, decorator

I want the functions to be part of the class I am building, but I get an error There is probably a problem that the decorator function  will be a function in the department. Is there a solution to the problem ? Thank you.

```
import engineio

class Websocket:

    def __init__(self):
        self.eio = engineio.Client()
        self.eio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
        self.eio.wait()

    # get error in this function       
    @eio.on('connect')
    def on_connect():
        print('connection established')
```

Comment: What would `eio` refer to in that context? Decorators are applied when a function is being defined (so when Python finds the `def ...` statement and executes it). Inside a class body that means *there is no class object yet*, let alone an instance of that class.

Comment: Also, `self.eio.wait()` **blocks**, you don't want to use that inside a `__init__` method of a class.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a decorator on a method where the decorator expression refers to an instance attribute. That's because decorators are executed *when the function they decorate is being created*. Inside a `class` statement body that means that when decorators are applied, there is no class yet, and without a class, there can't be any instances either.

You have two options:

- Just call `self.eio.on('connect')` in the `__init__` of your class, passing in a bound method:

  ```
  class Websocket:

      def __init__(self):
          self.eio = engineio.Client()
          self.eio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
          self.eio.on('connect', self.on_connect)
          # don't call wait, see below

      def on_connect(self):
          print('connection established')
  ```

  This works because by the time `__init__` is being called you have a class and an instance of that class (referenced by `self`), and `self.on_connect` returns a reference to a bound method (calling it will have `self` passed in). `@....` decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar, you don't *have* to use it. The [`engineio.Client.on()` method](https://python-engineio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#engineio.Client.on) accepts the handler as a second argument, but you could also use `self.eio.on('connect')(self.on_connect)`, which is a literal translation of what the decorator syntax does.
- Use a nested function inside `__init__`, and decorate that:

  ```
  class Websocket:

      def __init__(self):
          self.eio = engineio.Client()
          self.eio.connect('http://localhost:5000')

          @self.eio.on('connect')
          def on_connect():
              print('connection established')

          # don't call wait, see below


  but that makes it much harder to use that function directly from other code.
  ```

Note that the [`engineio.Client.wait()` method](https://python-engineio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#engineio.Client.wait) blocks, it doesn't return, until the connection has ended. You would not normally put that kind of call in the `__init__` method of a class!

Using a class to handle `engineio` events is great, but don't start the client connection from the class. I'd do this instead:

```
class Websocket:
    def __init__(self, socket_url):
        self.eio = engineio.Client()
        self.eio.connect(socket_url)
        self.eio.on('connect', self.on_connect)
        # other registrations

    def on_connect(self):
        # handle connection

    # other handlers

    def wait(self):
        self.eio.wait()

websocket = Websocket('http://localhost:5000)
websocket.wait()
```